# Calculating the shortest distance between coordinates in separate csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, distance

I have two CSV named File A and File B with coordinates (latitude and longitude). I'd like to automate the process by looping through all the coordinates and assign each coordinate with the one where the distance is shorter. The data frame is of the same shape and length, which means each coordinate must be assigned to its unique coordinates where the distance is shorter. Currently, I am doing it manually and it is tedious. Here are my codes.

```
from math import asin, cos, pi, sqrt

# coordinates in file A
lat1 = float(input('Latitude A'))
lon1= float(input('Longitude A'))

# coordinates in file B
lat2 = float(input('Latitude B'))
lon2= float(input('Longitude B'))


def distance(latA, lonA, latB, lonB):
    p = pi/180 # in radians
    a =  0.5 - cos((latB-latA)*p)/2 + cos(latA*p) * cos(latB*p) * (1-cos((lonB-lonA)*p))/2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a)) #2*R*asin...
```

This is how the data looks in both CSV files as shown in the picture below, however, I'd like to add two columns, one for the calculated distances in meters and the other for the corresponding coordinate with the shortest distance.

[image]

Comment: Could you show a row from the CSV file?

Comment: What does the header row look like?

Comment: So both files are in that format? Try editing your answer to more precisely show an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit what you want to achieve? Do you want to pair each coordinate from `file1` with its closest point at `file2`?

Comment: So compare each line in file 1 to every line in file 2, and output the pair with the shortest distance? Are two lines in file 1 allowed to both pair to the same line in file 2?

Comment: @tripleee that is what  I am trying to do, but the two line in file one is not allowed to pair to the same line in file two, they should be unique

Comment: @jpnadas ye that is what I am  trying to do

Comment: What would be your rule if `pair_1` from `file_1` is clostest to `pair_1` from `file_2`, but `pair_2` from `file_1` is also closest to  `pair_1` from `file_2`? Find the next closest pair? This will make the results dependent on the order of the loop...

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed the [tag:python-2.7] tag from this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `distance` function is correct, try something like

```py
import csv

with open('file2.csv') as file2:
    f2csv = csv.reader(file2)
    f2pairs = [line for line in f2csv]

with open('file1.csv') as file1:
    f1csv = csv.reader(file1)
    for lat1, lon1 in f1csv:
        mindist = None
        for lat, lon in f2pairs:
            dist = distance(lat1, lon1, lat, lon)
            if mindist is None or dist<mindist:
                mindist, lat2, lon2 = dist, lat, lon
        print(lat1, lon1, mindist, lat2, lon2)
```

This just prints results to standard output, and prefers the first destination point with the shortest distance in the case of a tie. If you want CSV ouput or different handling of ties, those should be easy changes to make on your own (or post a new question about that if you still need help). If the CSV files have header lines or other inane decorations, you need to tweak the code to discard those, too.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention the requirement to pick unique pairs from file 2 for each item in file 1, which was subsequently mentioned in a comment, nor do we know exactly how to achieve this based on just that one comment, so I have not attempted to tackle that here. Again, ask a new question specifically about just that problem if you still need help (probably link back here, but also consult the guidance for providing a [mre]).

Answer (score 1):

#### Determine the closest points

In order for you to get the output you want, you need to first determine what is the corresponding closest point form the second file. This can be done by iterating over all points on the first file and nesting that with another loop iterating over the coordinates on the second file.

Since you want to save it all to a file, I have saved each intended result into its own array, corresponding to each point on the first file.

Note: I am using `numpy` as `np` for this entire answer.

```
shortest_distances = []
closest_points = []

for c1 in coordinates_1:
    # Compute the distance for each point
    distances = [distance(c1, c2) for c2 in coordinates_2]
    # Determine the shortest
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    closest_points.append(coordinates_2[index])
    shortest_distances.append(distances[index])
```

### Stacking the results

Since each output will be correlated with its point on the first file, you can simply stack it horizontally to get what you want.

```
result = np.hstack((coordinates_1, closest_points, np.reshape(shortest_distances, (3, 1))))
```

Note that, I had to invoke `np.reshape()` on the `shortest_distances` list, so it would have 2 dimensions and then `np.hstack` would work.

#### Printing the result to a CSV

Finally, we can invoke `np.savetxt()` to save the result to a csv file.

```
np.savetxt("result.csv", result, delimiter=",")
```

#### Complete code

Here is the complete code

```
import numpy as np


def distance(point1, point2):
    R = 12742  # Earth radius, in KM
    p = np.pi / 180  # in radians
    lat1 = point1[0]
    lat2 = point2[0]

    lon1 = point1[1]
    lon2 = point2[1]

    a = 0.5 - np.cos((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 + np.cos(lat1 * p) * np.cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - np.cos((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2
    return R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))


coordinates_1 = np.loadtxt('coordinates1.csv', delimiter=',')
coordinates_2 = np.loadtxt('coordinates2.csv', delimiter=',')

shortest_distances = []
closest_points = []

for c1 in coordinates_1:
    # Compute the distance for each point
    distances = [distance(c1, c2) for c2 in coordinates_2]
    # Determine the shortest
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    closest_points.append(coordinates_2[index])
    shortest_distances.append(distances[index])

result = np.hstack((coordinates_1, closest_points, np.reshape(shortest_distances, (3, 1))))

# save to a csv file
np.savetxt("result.csv", result, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: I guess `np` here refers to NumPy, a popular but non-standard third-party library.

Comment: Yeah... I have that alias on the complete code, but good catch, I will include that in the beginning to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done after reinterpreting the question.

- parse the files and put the coordinates into lists
- then find all shortest unique pairs, put those in a list
- resort the shortest pairs back to the order of file 1
- output coordinate 1, coordinate 2 and the distance to output file `coords_out.csv`

```py
CSV_DELIMITER = ',' 

filename_1 = 'file2.csv'
filename_2 = 'file1.csv'


class Coordinate():
    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, file, line):
        self.lat = latitude
        self.lon = longitude
        self.file = file
        self.line = line

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lat}, {self.lon}'

def extract(line):
    lat, lon = line.split(CSV_DELIMITER)
    return (float(lat), float(lon))

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    
    p = pi/180 # in radians
    a =  0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p))/2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a)) #2*R*asin...

coords_1 = []
coords_2 = []

    
with open(filename_1) as file1, open(filename_2) as file2:

    # skip the header lines
    file1.readline()
    file2.readline()

    # iterate over both files simultaneously
    for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(file1, file2)):
        print(f'{line1}')

        # extract values and add them to a list
        lat1, lon1 = extract(line1)
        lat2, lon2 = extract(line2)
        coords_1.append(Coordinate(lat1, lon1, 'file1', i))
        coords_2.append(Coordinate(lat2, lon2, 'file2', i))

# now we find the shortest distance between coordinates
coords_1_order = coords_1[:] # copy order for later
shortest_distances = []

for x in range(min(len(coords_1), len(coords_2))):
    smallest_d = None
    
    for i, coord_1 in enumerate(coords_1):
        for j, coord_2 in enumerate(coords_2):
            d = distance(coord_1.lat, coord_1.lon,
                coord_2.lat, coord_2.lon)
            if (smallest_d == None) or (d < smallest_d[0]):
                smallest_d = (d, coord_1, coord_2, i, j)
    
    # add the smallest found distance to a list and make sure these coordinates aren't used again in the next loop
    shortest_distances.append(smallest_d)
    coords_1.pop(smallest_d[3])
    coords_2.pop(smallest_d[4])


# Then we sort the distances back to the order of file 1
sorted_back = []

for c in coords_1_order:
    for d_info in shortest_distances:
        if c == d_info[1]:
            sorted_back.append(d_info)          

# check if the sorting went okay
assert len(sorted_back) == len(shortest_distances), "sorting went horribly wrong, array lengths dont match"
                        
with open('coords_out.csv', 'w') as out:
    
    # write headers
    out.write(f'lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, distance\n')
    
    for distance_info in sorted_back:
        d, c1, c2, i, j = distance_info
        # output coordinate 1, coordinate 2 and the distance to output file
        out.write(f'{c1}, {c2}, {d}\n')
```

I've added a small `Coordinate` class that also keeps track of information on the file and line a coordinate was found at.

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it has to be. In any case, extra points for the `assert`!

Comment: @jpnadas Well, complicated is a relative term, but I do agree that my solution is a bit convoluted. I wanted to find a way without using extra libraries, mostly because I don't have much experience with different libraries myself. Looking at your answer, I wish I knew how to even look up such methods! `hstack`?? I'm afraid of being dependent on code I don't understand so I always try to keep it as raw as possible.  I think my way of finding shortest distances is also very tedious, but it works. Divide and conquer would have been better...

Comment: Fair point @Queuebee. I agree with you that not relying on third party libraries is often a good approach. However, you are also running into the risk of always having to reinvent the wheel yourself, and most likely your implementation will not be as efficient as the one at a library. That said, your point is That is exactly why I tend to avoid libraries with fancy data structures that aim to do everything for you (read `pandas` here). In any case, `numpy` is quite a handy library to get familiar with, and it is very similar to the way `matlab` operates.

Comment: I will definitely start exploring `numpy` more! And probably will be forced to learn `pandas` soon :')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the closest pair of coordinates for a given line of the file, it sounds like you want the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to parse the files into lists of lists.

From there, iterate through one of the lists, and find the shortest distance by checking all of the coordinates in the second list.

Something like this, assuming you have already loaded both lists to some variables

```py
for coordinate in list1:
    closest_coordinate = None
    for second_coord in list2:
        displacement = distance(coordinate, second_coord)
        if closest_coordinate = None or displacement < closest_coord[1]:
            closest_coordinate = (second_coord, displacement)
   # Do something with this info, maybe have a list of coordinate pairs and their distance?
```